# ¿Cual es la buena practica en cuanto a la estructura de las carpetas en templates, en Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django

***Soy nuevo en Django y me gustaria saber ¿Cual es la buena practica en cuanto a la estructura de la carpetas en templates, en Django?***

Ya sea la estructura de buena practica y la estructura profesionalmente(creo).

Es decir donde estaría **'base.html'**, donde estarían los archivos **'.htmls'** que extienden de **'base.html'**, etc. La estructura en si de los archivos.

También la estructura de la carpeta **'static'** donde van los archivos **'.css'**, **'.js'**, etc

**Desde ya gracias por sus respuestas!**

Comment: Por lo amplia de tu pregunta, lo más probable es que la cierren, ya que cualquier persona puede tener un concepto diferente de cómo se puede estructurar una aplicación con Django. Sin embargo mi consejo para ti es que leas la documentación de Django donde te dan una referencia de cómo sería ideal hacerlo, o leas libros de Django donde podrás aprender eso y mucho más, además de demasiadas buenas prácticas

Comment: ok gracias por tu comentario!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día:

Mi primera respuesta sería, como te sientas mas cómodo de organizar tus documentos.

1. Para mi al crear un proyecto, separo el entorno virtual de esa carpeta del proyecto.
2. Estando en el proyecto, creo un carpeta apps y dentro de esa carpeta muevo mis aplicaciones.
3. Creo un requirements.txt para registrar todas mis librerías y cuando descargo mi proyecto de un repositorio por ejemplo bitbucket, al descargar con el comando `pip install -r requeriments.txt` se instala todas mis librerías.
4. Y para mis archivos estáticos y media, creo las carpetas dentro del proyecto
5. Para mi la carpeta "templates" por defecto lo creo `Pycharm` dentro del proyecto. 
   `├───

   ├─── project
   │    ├─── apps
   │    │    ├─── app_1
   │    │    ├─── app_2
   │    │    └─── app_3
   │    ├─── manage.py
   │    ├─── static
   │    │    ├─── css
   │    │    ├─── images
   │    │    └─── js
   │    ├─── media
   │    │    ├─── 
   │    ├─── templates
   │    │    ├─── base.html
   │    │    └─── index.html
   │    └─── wsgi.py
   ├────└─── requirements.txt`

   Mi entorno como escribí líneas arriba, va separado de todo esto.

Comment: Generalmente cada app tiene su propia carpeta static que posteriormente se recopilan en la ruta indicada en el STATIC_ROOT con el comando collectstatic.